# Purging old commits with TortoiseGit

Tags: git, tortoisegit

My repository is 1GB in size according to BitBucket.

I have commits going all the way back to the start of 2017.

How to I truncate my history? For example, I have a certain tag XXX and I would like to delete all commits from XXX back to the initial commit. So that the repository is smaller.

I tried this on my PC:

```
ajtru@DESKTOP-4OHL3UQ MINGW64 /d/My Programs/2017/MeetSchedAssist (master)
$ git count-objects -vH
count: 0
size: 0 bytes
in-pack: 13336
packs: 1
size-pack: 575.46 MiB
prune-packable: 0
garbage: 0
size-garbage: 0 bytes
```

So I don't understand why the online bit-bucket repository is over 1GB.

> @MrTux Maybe you still have lots of remote branches on BitBucket, Git won't throw away commit if they are referenced from a branch/tag

I only have **one branch** on the remote server, but I do have **a lot of tags**:

[image: Tags]

Comment: Without rewriting history (e.g., rebasing), you cannot remove history. Git by design, uses a chaining of oll commits. So, altering an old commit will cause to modify the complete history and all following SHA1s (commit ids). Maybe you still have lots of remote branches on BitBucket, Git won't throw away commit if they are referenced from a branch/tag.

Comment: @MrTux If I delete tags, say v17.2.7 and older from both PC and remote would that improve things?

Comment: If the tags are on the branch, nothing changes (a tag is just a label for a commit).

Comment: @MrTux The tags are on the branch. I don't have to share my source code with third parties so I can rewrite history if that is the answer. How do I rewrite it so that the v18.0.0 tag is the "initial commit" and we get rid of anything older than that (I assume it is safe to do as I don't support v17.x anymore). Unless there is another way I am supposed to handle this ...

Comment: Do you have binaries in your repo?

Comment: @MrTux Yes, My APT file (application translations) and my HND (Help Topics) file are both binary files.

Comment: @MrTux I tried to download BFG Repo-Cleaner but I can't fathom how to install and use the JAR file. The readme makes so sense. Grrh.

Comment: I removed the files using bfg. The ironic thing is that bitbucket now says 1.6gb!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Did you force push all tags and remote? Otherwise they still point to the old history.

Comment: @MrTux I just did a force push aggressive call. I don’t know about the tags. And I have not deleted any tags.

Comment: Git need to run `git gc` to free unused data, maybe that is not run on BitBucket automatically or just in bigger intervals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without rewriting history (e.g., rebasing), you cannot remove/alter history. Git by design, uses a chaining of all commits. So, altering an old commit will cause to modify the complete history and all following SHA1s (commit ids). Maybe you still have lots of remote branches on BitBucket (which are not included in your main master branch), Git won't throw away commit if they are referenced from a branch/tag. - For that reason it is important that you force push all branches and (or delete all unured) tags after the rebasing or altering history - otherwise they still point to the old history (which cannot be deleted because some tags/branches points to it).

Big repositories often result from the fact, that the commits contain binaries. if those can be generated using the source, those should not be included in the commits. - If you want to publish them, some platforms provide the option the attach files to tags (oftentimes called releases).

Comment: Ok. But I only have one branch local and one branch remote.

Comment: Bitbucket have run `Git GC` on my repository and it has now gone down to under 600 MB. :)